# How to get the managers chain of command

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

TODO: Implement this method.*  You will need to use a for-loop for this part.*  *  Retrieves the manager's chain of command as a {@code List<Manager>}, starting with their direct {@code Manager},*  followed by that {@code Manager}'s {@code Manager}, and so on, until the top of the hierarchy is reached.*  *  The returned list should never be or contain {@code null}.*  *  If the manager does not have a {@code Manager}, an empty*  {@code List<Manager>} should be returned.** @return a {@code List<Manager>} that represents the manager's chain of command,*/I am unable to retrieve the chain of command like they are asking but I can get the empty array if a manager does not have a manager.

```
public List<Manager> getChainOfCommand() {

    List<Manager> chainOfCommand = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= chainOfCommand.size(); i++) {
        return chainOfCommand;
    }
    
    return chainOfCommand;
    
}
```

Comment: Why is it that you are using hashCode in `i <= chainOfCommand.hashCode()`?  That loops is likely going to run for thousands or millions of iterations.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not properly formatted, and the code you added is meaningless. Please explain your question, and make a good-faith attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Manager> getChainOfCommand() {

        List<Manager> chainOfCommand = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for(Manager m = manager; m != null; m = m.getManager()) {
            chainOfCommand.add(m);
        }

        return chainOfCommand;

    }
```